# Duplicate mysqld process causing ERROR 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: macos, mysql, macos-sierra

I'm on macOS 10.12 and getting the familiar `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'`. But I don't think it's one of the usual culprits.

The socket file `/tmp/mysql.sock` is missing, but `mysqld` is running. In fact there seem to be two `mysqld` processes:

```
$ ps -axx | grep mysqld
  63 ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql
 109 ??         0:00.27 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid
 267 ??         0:00.20 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/Jonathans-iMac.pid
```

I think I installed and uninstalled a few versions of mysql a while back. So maybe an old instance is hanging around, getting in the way?

I can't find an old install, though. And I can't even kill the second second `mysqld` process (I think that's the bad one) without it restarting right away. Seems `mysqld_safe` just restarts it.

Sometimes rebooting the whole system magically gets things working. There are still two `mysqld` processes, but at least `/tmp/mysql.sock` is created and I can access my databases as normal. Other times, rebooting doesn't help.

I've looked for an extra `.plist` file that might be responsible for the extra `mysqld` process, but no luck:

```
$ locate plist | grep mysql
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.mysql.launchd.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.mysql.mysql.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/com.mysql.prefpane.plist
```

Here are the contents of /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true />
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
  <string>--user=mysql</string>
</array>
```

and /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>         
<string>com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProcessType</key>       <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>          <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>         <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>         <true/>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>     <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>          <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>         <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>       <integer>600</integer>
    <key>Program</key>           <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
            <string>--user=_mysql</string>
            <string>--basedir=/usr/local/mysql</string>
            <string>--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data</string>
            <string>--plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin</string>
            <string>--log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err</string>
            <string>--pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid</string>
        </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>  <string>/usr/local/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any ideas how to identify and correct the source of the problem?

Comment: I *think* /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist should be removed, but I'm not 100% on OSX these days and have no way to test anyway.

Comment: I'll post that as a solution then, if you wouldn't mind accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted yourself, it seems that mysqld is being started twice. It seems at some point you've ran two different versions of the installers, which have installed in different locations, and not picked up on one another.

removing one or the other from

```
$ locate plist | grep mysql 
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist 
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Should solve your issue.